# Does changing an HTML element's position to absolute also changes the content category of the element?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS's positioning and HTML's content categories. And I wonder why adding `position: absolute;` inside `header` element in `style.css` results in a narrow block of header element on my browser.

I expected the header to be a block-level element and stretching out to the border of the body element, that is, touching the border of my screen.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Please Participate in Our Survey!</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>Question 1</li>
      <li>Question 2</li>
      <li>Question 3</li>
      <li>Question 4</li>
      <li>Question 5</li>
      <li>Question 6</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to our survey!</h1>
    <p>We're looking forward to getting your answers so we can make sure our products and services are the best they can be!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
    <h2>I like participating in physical activity such as running, swimming, or biking.</h2>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Disagree</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Neutral</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Agree</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
    <h2>I try to keep up to date with the latest fashion in active wear.</h2>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Disagree</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Neutral</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Agree</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
    <h2>I purchase clothing online regularly.</h2>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Disagree</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Neutral</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Agree</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 4</h4>
    <h2>I try to buy goods that are designed and/or manufactured in my home country.</h2>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Disagree</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Neutral</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Agree</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 5</h4>
    <h2>I look to famous athletes when trying to choose what to wear when training.</h2>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Disagree</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Neutral</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <h3>Agree</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #466995;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #466995;
  position: absolute; // This line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  border: thin solid red !important;
}

ul {
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li:hover {
  color: #DBE9EE;
}

h1 {
  color: #466995;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

h3 {
  color: #466995;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 30px;
}

h4 {
  color: #466995;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

p {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome {
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.question {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.answer {
  border: 1px solid #466995;
  margin: 20px;
}

.answer:hover {
  background: #C0D6DF;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: when you set an element's position to absolute, it then taken out of the document flow, meaning it will be placed as if it's the only one that exist, if it's parent doesn't have position relative, then it will be relative to the  initial containing block.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Can you explain a bit further? The containing element/parent of `header` is `body`, which is also block-level and has default `static` property. But why does this change the width of `header`? Isn't it only causing following elements to ignore `header` and move up to align with the top border of `body`?

Comment: normally a block level element will take 100% of it's parent width, the body is a special element, it's width is defined by the `viewport`, that's why your header fills the width, now when you set the header to `position:absolute` it is then taken out of the document flow, and becomes relative to it's first positioned (not static) ancestor element, if none exists then it is relative to the initial containing block which is the vewport. why the header shrinks in width that is because it is not static anymore, static means `Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow`

Comment: @ZohirSalak sorry but the fact that the element is taken out of the flow doesn't explain the width behavior .. make the element inline-block and you will have exactly the same behavior and the element will remain in-flow ... as the below answer, it's how absolute element have their width calculated based on the specificiation

Comment: oh right, the answer makes sense, i was speaking out of the top of my head, didn't even know about the equality thing.

Comment: Not sure what "content category" means here, if you're asking about the element's content model in HTML, HTML and CSS are separate languages and CSS cannot affect the semantics of an HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

An in-flow, non-replaced block level box observes this equality:

```
margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + width + 
padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right = width of containing block
```

If, as in your case, the width is specified as `auto`, the width is stretched to take up all the necessary space to make the equality hold.

An absolutely positioned, non-replaced block level box observes this equality:

```
left + margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + width +
padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right + right = width of containing block
```

First, if as in your case, `left` and `right` are `auto`, the width is the minimum necessary to contain the content (i.e. it is shrink-to-fit), and the right value is stretched to take up all the necessary space to make the equality hold.

If you set `left` and `right` to `0`, *then* with `width`being auto, the width is stretched to take up all the necessary space to make the equality hold, and your header will  grow to touch the border or both sides.

For more cases and details, see [Section 10.3 Calculating widths and margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) of the CSS 2.2 spec.

Comment: I would probably add the *shrink-to-fit* word somewhere to make it more clear .. not sure if saying *the right value is stretched to take up all the necessary space to make the equality hold.* make it clear that it's a shrink-to-fit behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif - thanks, amended. There's always a balance to knowing which aspects to gloss over and which to include.  For example, for simplicity's sake, I've assumed ltr direction.